# Removing items from one ArrayList from another ArrayList in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding items to two different arraylists, I then want to remove any items from the first arraylist that exist in the second one. I am running into problems trying to remove the the duplicate values. The Item exists in the arraylist that I'm trying to remove it from so I'm unsure why it won't work. I'm teaching myself VBA for this project so apologies if the code is redundant or messy.

Here is the section of code that is causing me issues:

```
Set Tbl = Sheets("Sheet6").ListObjects("table17")
For x = 1 To Tbl.ListRows.Count
    UAapp.Add Tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 3)
Next x


For Each Item In App
    UAapp.Remove Item
    Stop
Next Item
```

I tried using both each and to statements to create the loop. When I use object watch I can see that the Item exists in the UAapp arraylist, but when the loop iterates, it moves to the next item without removing it.

Comment: My be, you should remove items from last item to first item, or by index. When remove item, array will be rearranged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
UAapp.Add Tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 3)
```

what are you adding to the arraylist?  You might expect it's the content of that cell, but you're actually adding a reference to the cell itself.  You need to add `.Value` to make sure you're adding the cell's value to the list and not a reference to the cell.

For example:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim lstA As Object, lstB As Object, c As Range, itm
    Set lstA = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set lstB = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For Each c In Range("A1:A5")
        lstA.Add c.Value 'note use of .Value
    Next c
    
    For Each c In Range("B1:B5")
        lstB.Add c.Value
    Next c
    
    For Each itm In lstA
        If lstB.contains(itm) Then lstB.Remove itm
    Next itm
    
    For Each itm In lstB
        Debug.Print itm
    Next itm
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding .Value to the end of "Tbl.DataBodyRange(x , 3)" and to the end of my other .add formula worked. I could have sworn I tried and got an error about invalid object or something, but I tried it again and everything is working. Your explanation of the fact that I was setting the arraylist equal to the reference of the cell and not the value of the cell helped me understand where I was making my mistake and why the code was not running properly. Thank you for the time spent helping me with this